# Access data saved in ModelForm in views form_valid function

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

Suppose I have two models: Payment and User

models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(A, blank=True)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    has_paid = models.BooleanField(...)
```

forms.py

```
CreatePayment(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    fields = '__all__'
```

Now, when I submit the CreatePayment form, I can select multiple users for each payment (and vice versa, because multiple users can be paid for in a single payment and each user can make multiple payments). Is there a way I can edit the `form_valid` method in views.py so that I can make the `has_paid` field True only for the users selected in the `CreatePayment` form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you can, but are you sure that's what you want? There's a single `has_paid` field per user, but a many-to-many relationship with Payments so that there are potentially many payments for each user.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I could not find any other way to do this actually. What I want here is that a single user can choose other users in their group(including themselves) while making a payment. Is there a better way to do that by making modifications to my models?

Comment: I think you need to explain your use case in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Do you actually need a model form? Check out Django's class-based views, which have some built-in functions to auto-generate model forms.

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class PaymentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Payment
    fields = '___all___'

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.cleaned_data['users'].update(has_paid=True)
        return super().form_valid(form, **kwargs)
```

Of course you might have to adjust this snippet a bit.